# MySQL database to store user comments

Tags: android, mysql

I'm currently developing an application which aims to provide users with a map with which they can navigate and which will also track their position. Another part to the application is that the user must be able to share a comment that comes to mind (similar to Tweets/Facebook status) which will be viewable to other users of the application. The idea is that these comments would be categorised depending on the nature of the comment.

However, as this is my first android application and my programming experience is quite minimal, I'm having a little bit of difficulty. I have integrated Google Maps into the application, however I'm stuck on the Comments section. I've been told I need to use a MySQL Database and use PHP as the go between with Android & the db?

I'm not really experienced using databases and so I'm unsure if I could implement some kind of category system for the comments? Ideally, the user would be presented with a list view of the categories and then select an appropriate one which would show all the comments posted to that category, much like a Twitter feed. Can this be achieved using MySQL? Am I on the right path?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try to post a specific question, this way we could provide you a good/correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forgive me if I target this at the wrong level, from you question I assume you are very new to this game.

For your users to share content with each other they are going to have to talk to a middle man, a server, your server. This server is going need to be running a customer website (webservice) and record all users comments and then feed those comments back to all users running your applications on their phones.

How those comments are stored and what language this webservice runs on is upto you.

For languages you could pick any some of the most popular (in no particular order) are:

- Java
- C#
- Perl
- PHP
- JavaScript
- Python
- etc.

With the language you choose you are going to provide an Api to your application (look into Json Over Rest).

The other thing your service is going to need to do is store this information, databases are good places to store information, again there are a lot to choose from. Starting with traditional Sql Databases:

- MySql
- PostgreSQL
- MS-Sql-Server
- DB2
- Oracle
- etc.

All of these are going to be well able to handle you requirements. You may also wish too look at a [NoSql](http://nosql-database.org/) alternative.

So when a user adds a comment in your application your application opens an internet connection to your server and sends the comment. The server [PHP | Java | Python | etc.] checks to make sure the comment is OK and is from a registered user, then sends it to the database. The database [MySql | MS-SQL | DB2 | etc] writes this comment to a table. When your application wants to display comments from other users it will send what categories it is interested in to your server, which will ask the database for the most appropriate comments, the data base will retrieve these and pass them back to the server which will in turn pass these onto your client.

In answer to your question:

Yes MySql and PHP running on your server will be able to handle this, so will a large number of other tools.

Please do not start writing to databases until you understand about [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)